# Get Typeorm default DatasourceManager (previously getConnectionManager())

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

In typeorm the getConnectionManager() is deprecated, and the createConnection() is deprecated to
new DataSource({options}). How can I get datasource manager so that I can get the default connection.
I am using multiple databases and I want to stop the default connection and attempt to connect to another one and run migrations.

Here is how I am curently doing it, it works, but it is deprecated so I want to use stable methods.
I checked typeorm docs but I couldn't find any answers.

```
const connectionManager = getConnectionManager();

    if (
      connectionManager.has('default') &&
      connectionManager.get('default').isConnected
    ) {
      await connectionManager.get('default').close();
    }
    const connection = await createConnection({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'Password@1',
      database: databaseName,
      migrations: ['dist/database/migrations/*.js'],
      name: databaseName,
    });

   try {
      await connection.runMigrations();
      console.log('Migrations ran successfully...');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log('Failed to run migrations....');
    }
```